# How to add multiple application.properties files in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application that is divided in several modules.
The main module runs the application and has an `application.properties` file in the resources folder. I'm wondering if I can add another properties file in a submodule to separate properties that are belonging to that module and how to make this working (because it is not).

```
+main_module
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +my/package/Application.java
        +resources/application.properties
+support_module
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +resources/application.properties
```

So, this is the current situation. Clearly the properties file in the module `support_module` is not read causing a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, while if I put the content in the other properties file everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using maven modules by introducing a parent pom.xml?

Comment: Sure I have a parent pom

Comment: This works https://stackoverflow.com/a/64977088/1352530, but I am not sure how nasty and prone to side-effects can be having a main configuration under config folder when running on different environments

Comment: Perhaps not a good idea seeing this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9128

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not work when using Maven or Gradle. The reason is that when the artifact (jar most likely since you are using Spring Boot) is created, there will only be one `application.properties` file in the root.

I suggest you either change the name of the properties file on the support module and then configure Spring Boot to look for that file as well (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862357/2504224) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598314/merge-properties-files-with-maven-assembly) answer for pointers), or use some kind of merging task for your build tool (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213550/2504224) perhaps)

Comment: The first suggestion looks interesting. How can I instruct Spring Boot to look for the properties in the secondary module?

Comment: @mat_boy You should also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30213550/2504224) SO thread

Comment: Aaaah! So I just need to use `spring.config.location` in the main `application.properties`. Cool

Comment: I opted for the annotation from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30213550/2504224), thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://roufid.com/load-multiple-configuration-files-different-directories-spring-boot/) is another walkthrough about how to set the java command to point to multiple property files

Comment: this is not accurate, if you have multiple application.properties (1 per profile) all those are inside the jar

Answer (score 16):

The problem is exactly what @geoand describes. Spring boot loads top level `application.properties` and ignores any properties file with the exact name located in other jars.

But I didn't find any concrete implementation on how to fix this problem, so here it is for those who wants to know the implementation.

Consider this project configuration:

```
+main_module
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +my/package/Application.java
      +resources/application.properties
+module_aa
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +my/package/config/ModuleAAConfig.java
      +resources/module_aa.properties
+module_bb
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +my/package/config/ModuleBBConfig.java
      +resources/module_bb.properties
```

Now to load properties for each sub modules correctly we need to add `@PropertySource` annotation on the configs of each module i.e `ModuleAAConfig.java, ModuleBBConfig.java`.

Example:

`ModuleAAConfig.java`

```java
package my.package.config;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(
    ignoreResourceNotFound = false,
    value = "classpath:module_aa.properties")
public class ModuleAAConfig {}
```

`ModuleBBConfig.java`

```java
package my.package.config;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(
    ignoreResourceNotFound = false,
    value = "classpath:module_bb.properties")
public class ModuleBBConfig {}
```

---

**Bonus:**

If you want to load profile specific property, you can do so by utilizing spring variables e.g.

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:module_aa-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

Answer (score 10):

Spring Boot reads the property files in the following order. ([From Spring Boot in Action](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files))

> 1. Externally, in a /config subdirectory of the directory from which the application is run
> 2. Externally, in the directory from which the application is run
> 3. Internally, in a package named “config”
> 4. Internally, at the root of the classpath
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

So placing `application.properties` in a `config` sub-directory will give it a higher priority. In the following configuration, the `application.properties` from `module_a` will take precedence. You can add common defaults in `application.properties` and override them in individual modules by placing the configuration file in `config/application.properties`.

```
+common_module
  +src
    +main
      +java
      +resources/application.properties
+module_a
  +src
    +main
      +java
        +my/package/Application.java
      +resources/config/application.properties
```

Comment: Will it search a value for a property in the next place, when it had found a properties-file in the previous one, but not found a value for that property in that file?

Comment: I guess this will not work when having more than one submodules with specific configuration.

Answer (score 9):

You can also refer to an explicit location using the spring.config.location environment property (comma-separated list of directory locations, or file paths)

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

For more information [click](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) here

Answer (score 1):

I found that `spring.config.import` in my `application.properties` brought in the additional properties file.

```
spring.config.import=file:./src/main/resources/application-local.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can design your modules more properly and implement `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to load they personal properties files automatically.

Please see my detailed answer: [How to inherit application.properties in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718763/how-to-inherit-application-properties-in-spring/72793561#72793561)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `application.properties` is not possible in same artifacts but
you can have

```
 application.properties 
 application.yml
```

in the same artifacts. This may help to separate concerns.