# Spring is getting properties from different module. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

My maven project has three modules:

```
Dummy-project
  - Module A
    - Module A1
    - Module A2
      - src/main
        - java
          - HttpMetaDataUtil.java
        - resources
          - config/beta
            - application.properties
  - Module B
    - src/main
        - resources
          - config/beta
            - application.properties
  - Module C
```

In module A2, using file HttpMetaDataUtil.java, I want to read contents from properties file (residing inside module A2 only).

**HttpMetaDataUtil.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config/beta/application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api.verification")
public class HttpMetaDataUtil {

    private Map<String, String> smartCard;


}
```

**Module A2/src/main/resources/config/beta/application.properties**

```
# SmartCard related properties
api.verification.smartCard.path=https:dummy_data
api.verification.smartCard.retryDelay=1000
api.verification.smartCard.serviceTimeout=30000
```

But smartCard map is getting set as null.

When I put the above properties config in Module B/src/main/resources/config/common/application.properties, it is taking the properties from this file.

**Module B/src/main/resources/config/beta/application.properties**

```
# SmartCard related properties
api.verification.smartCard.path=https:dummy_data
api.verification.smartCard.retryDelay=1000
api.verification.smartCard.serviceTimeout=30000
```

This means that **HttpMetaDataUtil.java** (residing under module A2) has classpath set for Module B.

I verified it by changing the **@PropertySource** line in **HttpMetaDataUtil.java** to `@PropertySource("classpath:config/beta/application_new.properties")` and creating  **application_new.properties** file only in **module A2**, and it is throwing fileNotFound exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/beta/application_new.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

When I created **application_new.properties** file also in **module B**, it is picking properties from this file.

Can anyone please tell why Module A2 class is picking properties from Module B? Is something I am missing related to classpath?

Comment: Can you please change `@Component` To `@Configuration`

Comment: I did. It is throwing the same error.
One thing to note is my main application file is located in module B.

Comment: Check this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941862/spring-boot-configuration-in-a-multi-module-maven-project

Comment: Is module B a dependency of Module A?

Comment: @M.Deinum No. Actually module A1 and A2 are dependencies of module B.

Comment: Which explains it. The name and location are the same (root of classpath) and it will only read a single file from that location. The one in Module B has a higher precedence. Either use a single file for all or change the names.