# Spring (not boot) load multiple yml files from multiple projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles, spring-properties

So I have read dosens af articles on how to configure Spring boot to be aware of more yml files than `application.yml` and how to include these - even from subprojects. It is however hard to come by articles describing the same for "pure" Spring. I think however that i'm heading in the right direction I just can't get my configuration values back.

It's a straight forward multi-project gradle build with - for simplicity - two projects. One project is the "main" spring project - ie. Spring Context is initialized in this project. The other is a "support" module with some database entities and datasource configuration. We use annotation based configuration.

I would like to be able to define a set of configuration properties in the support module and based on whatever spring profile is active, the datasource configuration is loaded accordingly.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229793/how-to-add-multiple-application-properties-files-in-spring-boot) SA post got me quite far following the different links in the different answers and composing my solution from this. The structure and code is as follows:

```
mainproject
  src
    main
      groovy
        Application.groovy
    resourcers
      application.yml

submodule
  src
    main
      groovy
        PropertiesConfiguration.groovy
        DataSource.groovy
    resources
      datasource.yml
```

The `PropertiesConfiguration.groovy` adds the `datasource.yml` by using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configure() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlPropertiesFactoryBean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean()
        yamlPropertiesFactoryBean.setResources(new ClassPathResource("datasource.yml"))
        configurer.setProperties(yamlPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject())
        return configurer
    }
}
```

The `Datasource.groovy` should then read values based on the spring profile using (code reduced for readability):

```
@Autowired
Environment env

datasource.username = env.getProperty("datasource.username")
```

The `env.getProperty` returns null. No matter what spring profile is active. I can access the configuration value using the @Value annotation, however then the active profile is not respected and it return a value even if it is not defined for that profile. My yml looks (something) like this:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: development

datasource:
  username: sa
  password:
  databaseUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:tests
  databaseDriver: org.h2.Driver
```

I can from Application.groovy inspect my ApplicationContext using a debugger and confirm that my `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` exist and the values are loaded. Inspecting `applicationContext.environment.propertySources` it is NOT there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` does not add properties to `Environment`. Using something like `@PropertySource("classpath:something.properties")` on the class level of your configuration class will add properties to `Environment`, but sadly this does not work with `yaml`-files.

So, you would have to manually add the properties read from the `yaml` file to your `Environment`. Here is one way to do this:

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer config(final ConfigurableEnvironment confenv) {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yamlProperties.setResources(new ClassPathResource("datasource.yml"));
    configurer.setProperties(yamlProperties.getObject());

    confenv.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("datasource", yamlProperties.getObject()));

    return configurer;
}
```

With this code, you can inject properties in either of these two fashions:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PropertiesConfiguration.class)
public class ConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Test
    public void props() {
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("datasource.username"));
        System.out.println(username);
    }
}
```

With the properties supplied in the question, this will print "sa" two times.

Edit: It doesn't seem that the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is actually needed now, so the code can be simplified to the below and still produce the same output.

```
@Autowired
public void config(final ConfigurableEnvironment confenv) {
    final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yamlProperties.setResources(new ClassPathResource("datasource.yml"));

    confenv.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("datasource", yamlProperties.getObject()));
}
```

Edit 2:

I see now that you are looking to use the yaml-file with multiple documents in one file, and Spring boot-style selection by profile. It does not seem to be possible using regular Spring. So I think you have to split your yaml files into several, named "datasource-{profile}.yml". Then, this should work (perhaps with some more advanced checking for multiple profiles, etc)

```
@Autowired
public void config(final ConfigurableEnvironment confenv) {
    final YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();

    yamlProperties.setResources(new ClassPathResource("datasource-" + confenv.getActiveProfiles()[0] + ".yml"));

    confenv.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("datasource", yamlProperties.getObject()));
}
```

Edit 3:

It could also be possible to use functionality from Spring boot without doing a full conversion of your project (I haven't actually tried it on a real project though). By adding a dependency to  `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE` I was able to get it working with the single `datasource.yml` and multiple profiles, like this:

```
@Autowired
public void config (final ConfigurableEnvironment confenv) {
    final YamlPropertySourceLoader yamlPropertySourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    try {
        final PropertySource<?> datasource =
                yamlPropertySourceLoader.load("datasource",
                                            new ClassPathResource("datasource.yml"),
                                            confenv.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
        confenv.getPropertySources().addFirst(datasource);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load datasource properties", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works - somewhat. The active spring profile is not taken into consideration and the last value in the yml file is always returned. Even though it is contained under a different spring profiles block. Is this only a Spring boot thing or should it work?

Comment: I think that would be spring boot specific. With regular Spring I think it would be more common to keep the properties in separate files.