# spring boot include configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to build includes of properties from other files in Spring boot on loading the app. Does Spring Boot provides anything like this?

`application.properties`

```
external_source_environment = classpath:source_UAT1.properties
//external_source_environment = classpath:source_PROD1.properties
```

`source_UAT1.properties`

```
source.url = http://oneexample_uat1.com
source.credentials = abc/cdw
```

`source_PROD1.properties`

```
source.url = http://oneexample_uat2.com
source.credentials = aaa/bbb
```

So in the code, I could just refer to properties name, while be able to switch the active file only (profiles won't work, since they are used for specifying environment where code is running, not selection between sources within already selected env):

```
@Configuration
public class Source {
  @Value("${source.url}")
  private String url
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple application.properties files in spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229793/how-to-add-multiple-application-properties-files-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Also, yes profiles will work. You have two profiles there `UAT1` and `PROD1`.

Comment: how do I enable profile based on other property value? @OrangeDog